# Counter in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a website for a survey, and I want to show the user the number of questions that are left to answer.

As the questions are dynamic, I read the total number of questions from the database to show in the counter.

Then each time the user answers a question (*the user chooses the answer from a radio button group*) I'll decrement the counter by one and so on.

I have the function which is called whenever the user clicks on a radio button and it works nicely. But I don't know how to represent the counter? and how to show the counter on the screen? and what values should I pass to that function? it would be helpful also if we can show the counter in a nice visual way, the counter should be always be visible even when the user scrolls up or down.

Each question is in a unique :

```
<div id="Q1">What is your gender?
<input type='radio' name='RQ1' value='Male' onClick="RadioClicked(Q1)" />
<input type='radio' name='RQ1' value='Female' onClick="RadioClicked(Q1)" />
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript function, for example I'm changing the background color to make sure the function works, but in this function I should decrement the counter:

```
function RadioClicked(Question){
        document.getElementById(Question).style.backgroundColor = "Gray";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var q = $('div[id^="Q"]').length // number of questions
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'Gray');
    var remained = q - $('input[type=radio]:checked').length // number of unanswered questions
    $('#remaining').text(remained)
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze6VP/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you have any idea how to display the counter in a nice way like a box that flows on the screen and which remains visible even when the user scrolls up or down?

Comment: @user1483799 you are welcome, you can use css `position: fixed`